# Why does snort can not alert this pcap?

Tags: snort, pcap, ids

the rule is

```
alert tcp any any <> any any (sid:11111;content:"GET";)
```

a file named http.pcap,in which has content

```
GET /s?wd=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6 HTTP/1.0
```

a config file named 1.conf

```
include /home/zhzhy/tmp/my.rules
```

and I run snort like

```bash
sudo snort -c /home/zhzhy/tmp/1.conf -r pcap/http.pcap
```

and the results is

```bash
Action Stats:
     Alerts:            0 (  0.000%)
     Logged:            0 (  0.000%)
     Passed:            0 (  0.000%)
Limits:
      Match:            0
      Queue:            0
        Log:            0
      Event:            0
      Alert:            0
Verdicts:
      Allow:           72 (100.000%)
```

why?
shouldn't it alert when it detect the "GET"?

Comment: Could you tell us more about your Snort install? Did you build it from source? What OS? Could you share your PCAP file? Using your rule, I generate two alerts from the http.cap file at https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#hypertext-transport-protocol-http.

Comment: I tried that http.cap file it's also alert,so I guess it's my pcap file which has some mistake...but it indeed has the "GET" word,I uploaded it.